# how to use placeholder ngContent for the inner html of a component

Tags: angular

I want to create a `frame` component so that it can be used like this in another component:

`page.component.html`

```
<frame>
     <span>My other content</span>
</frame>
```

And I'd like to use whatever is inside of the `<frame>` body (in this case a single span element) where I have some `#placeholder` element

`frame.component.html`

```
<h>title</h>
<toolbar>...</toolbar>
<sidenav-container>
   <sidenav>...</sidenav> 
   <ngContent #placeholder><ngContent> <!-- I want this to get replaced -->
</sidenav-container>
<footer>...</footer>
```

I tried looking at the code for [material design sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) but I didn't really understand it. and maybe doing more than `frame` which just passes it along.

I also don't want to do something like this:

```
<frame [placeholder]="page"></frame>
```

I just started learning angular so I might also just be missing the point. I couldn't find anywhere that explained what the insides of the selectors gets translated to or how the selector component can access that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after googling around some more I found what I wanted is called transclusion and in angular it is done using `<ng-content>`.

Unfortunately there isn't much documentation on it yet (see issue below). but the gist of it is we can do this:

`frame.component.html`

```
<h>title</h>
<toolbar>...</toolbar>
<sidenav-container>
  <sidenav>...</sidenav> 
  <ng-content selector="[frame-body]"><ng-content> <!-- I want this to get replaced -->
</sidenav-container>
<footer>...</footer>
```

and using it:

`page.component.html`

```
<frame>
  <span frame-body>Hello World!</span>
</frame>
```

references: 
https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/3099 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content

Comment: On newer Angular versions you may use "select" instead of "selector": select="[frame-body]"